# Container Managed Transaction: Behind the scene

Tags: transactions, ejb, jta

I understand that handling transactions in EJB are left to be taken care by EJB Container / Application server.

Now I want to understand this bit more, for example consider a scenario in which we have a distributed transaction (more than two resources as part of the transaction); I read that there are JTA, JTS for all this.

## My question is:

1) Does container implement the JTA spec for transaction handling?

2) Does Container provided JTS service?

If #1 and #2 aren't true then how does container provide the transaction support? Does it "borrow" functionality from some other open source project for doing these kind of work?

Can anyone help in understanding this?

PS: I did refer materials both online and book, but I am still not clear and hence asking this question.

Comment: Did you read the actual specifications?

Comment: @SteveC : Few pages, difficult to comprehend, that is why want to know a bit here and then refer to the specifications.

Answer (score 2):

The answers can be found in the latest EJB Specification.

*1) Does container implement the JTA spec for transaction handling?*

> **21.3.3 JTA 1.1 Requirements**
>
> The EJB container must include the JTA 1.1 extension, and it must
>   provide the javax.transaction.UserTransaction interface to enterprise
>   beans with bean-managed transaction demarcation through the
>   javax.ejb.EJBContext interface, and also in JNDI under the name
>   java:comp/UserTransaction, in the cases required by the EJB
>   specification. The other JTA interfaces are low-level transaction
>   manager and resource manager integration interfaces, and are not
>   intended for direct use by enterprise beans.

*2) Does Container provided JTS service?*

> **13.1.3 Relationship to JTA and JTS**.
>
> The EJB architecture does not require the EJB container to support the
>   JTS interfaces. The EJB architecture requires that the EJB container
>   support the JTA API defined in [8] and the Connector APIsdefined in
>   [15].

*3) If #1 and #2 aren't true then how does container provide the transaction support? Does it "borrow" functionality from some other open source project for doing these kind of work?*

I really don't get this questions. In general Oracle/Sun provide a set of interfaces or specification, each vendor (Glassfish, Weblogic, JBoss, etc...) will then provide its concrete implementation.

In the past, an application server had to be certified by Sun to be considered JEE compliant, I suppose it is exactly the same with Oracle. So, you can provide concrete implementation by means of open source libraries, someone else will decide if your server is compliant.